# Angular project update

Tags: angular, npm

I am upgrading an angular project following the suggestions [here](https://update.angular.io/?v=5.2-13.0). I completed the first step of updating the http client and all corresponding calls. I also made sure the node version is greater than 8.

Now when I run the next command:
`NG_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK=1 npx @angular/cli@6 update @angular/cli@6`, I get the following error.

```
./Release/.deps/Release/obj.target/fse/fsevents.o.d.raw Stats {
  dev: 16777221,
  mode: 33188,
  nlink: 1,
  uid: 501,
  gid: 20,
  rdev: 0,
  blksize: 4096,
  ino: 25225592,
  size: 1790,
  blocks: 8,
  atimeMs: 1650347794000,
  mtimeMs: 1650347794000,
  ctimeMs: 1650347794392.3928,
  birthtimeMs: 1650347794000,
  atime: 2022-04-19T05:56:34.000Z,
  mtime: 2022-04-19T05:56:34.000Z,
  ctime: 2022-04-19T05:56:34.392Z,
  birthtime: 2022-04-19T05:56:34.000Z
}
Your global Angular CLI version (6.2.9) is greater than your local
version (1.7.4). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
Error: Unexpected end of JSON input
Unexpected end of JSON input
```

However, if i run the project by running the command `ng serve`, the project run successfully. I would appreciate if someone can help me identify what this error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below step, I hope it work for you.

```
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@6
```